# Incorrect results of diffusion equation with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I want to resolve a PDE model, which is 1D heat diffusion equation with Neumann boundary conditions. The key problem is that I have some trouble in solving the equation numerically. Consider the following code:

```
h = 6000;
a = 200;
Dif = 3.67*10^-14*10^18;
Ni = 1;
deq = D[u[t, x], t] == Dif*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}]
ic = u[0, x] == If[0 <= x <= a , Ni, 0]
bc = {Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][t, h] == 0}
sol = NDSolve[{deq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, h}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, h},  PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I got a result, but a error was occurred.

```
NDSolve::ibcinc:
```

I know that this error suggests conflicts between initial condition and boundary conditions, although I have no idea where conflict come from.

In addition, as you can see, the value of x=0 is gradually increased with time in spite of Neumann conditions.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: To be more specifc, add `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 1000, 
    "MinPoints" -> 1000, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}` to `NDSolve` will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comment of @xzczd is very pertinent, but there are a lot of things to say about this subject. Among theses things :

- In your example `NDSolve` automatically chooses the "TensorProductGrid" method (as opposed to "FiniteElement"). This information is sometimes hard to find. I get it from experience (**Edit** [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/5467) is a question that asks how to know which method `NDSolve` has automatically chosen).
- This choice leads to the problem mentionned by @xzczd. This problem is complicated to analyse and it is not clearly documented. I'm speaking of this [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html)
- A more friendly approach is to use the Finite Element Method. With this method, the syntax for the Neumann boundary condition is not `Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == 0` but a syntax that use `NeumannValue`. The use of `NeumannValue` is a little bit disturbing at the beginning, but in your case it's very simple because the boundary condition equivalent to `Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == 0` is the default choice of `NDSolve` with the finite element method.

So, to get the solution,  just remove the boundary conditions and impose the finite elemnt method :

```
h = 6000;
a = 200;
Dif = 3.67*10^-14*10^18;
Ni = 1;
deq = D[u[t, x], t] == Dif*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}]
ic = u[0, x] == If[0 <= x <= a , Ni, 0]
sol = NDSolve[{deq, ic}, u, {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, h},Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, h},  PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Based on all of your comments, I got a preferable results. Thanks again.