# How to speed up integral of results of PDE model

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I want to get results of integral of PDE model result. The PDE model is 1D heat diffusion equation with Neumann boundary conditions. The key problem is that integral of PDE model result take too much time to calculate, and I haven't gottten the results yet. I consider the following code:

```
h = 6000;
a = 200;
Dif = 3.67*10^-14*10^18;
Ni = 1;

deqN = D[u[t, x], t] - Dif*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == 
      NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[0, x == h];
ic = u[0, x] == If[0 <= x <= a , Ni, 0]

sol = NDSolveValue[{deqN, ic}, u, {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, h}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.1}}}}];

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, h}, PlotRange -> Full, 
       PlotStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
Plot[NIntegrate[sol[t, x], {x, 0, a}], {t, 0, 60}]
```

[image]

I successfully got a result of the PDE calculation, but the code take lot of time in the integral part. It doesn't finish even I wait for a few hours.

Any suggestions how to speed it up or fix it?

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal This question isn't a duplicate of former question of OP, notice this time OP asked about performance tuning of numerical integration.

Comment: To be more specific, `core = u /. sol[[1]]; 
mid[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[core[t, x], {x, 0, a}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; 
Plot[mid@t, {t, 0, 60}] // AbsoluteTiming` will resolve your problem.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for pointing that out, My bad!

Comment: @xzczd OP used `NDSolveValue` so your suggestion doesn't seem to immediately run.

Comment: Maybe the `Method` values are overkill.   I simply used `sol = NDSolve[{deqN, ic}, u, {t, 0, 60}, {x, 0, h},  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]` as @Andre suggested [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139233/6358) and it ran very quickly.

Comment: @ChrisK Oh, didn't notice that. (I used the code in the previous post of OP. ) Then `mid[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[sol[t, x], {x, 0, a}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; Plot[mid@t, {t, 0, 60}] // AbsoluteTiming` is enough :)