# PDEs : automatic method choice : TensorProductGrid or FiniteElement?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

A problem that arises when we solve PDEs with `NDSolve[]` and `Method->Automatic` is how to know which method has been chosen :  `TensorProductGrid` or `FiniteElement` ?

The question is important because :

- NDSolve often use `TensorProductGrid` (wrongly I think) instead of `FiniteElement`. I guess the reason is historical :  `TensorProductGrid` is maybe 15 years older than `FiniteElement`. For compatibility reasons all forms of syntax that was leading to `TensorProductGrid` should continue to lead to this method.
- The wrong choice may lead to problems that are very, very advanced ([here for example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139206/5467))
- If we don't know which method is used, we don't know which documentation to read (the one for `TensorProductGrid`  or the one for `FiniteElement`) and these documentations are very consequent (and it's crucial to understand error messages).
- Even advanced user can't deduce the choice of the method from the syntax. For example, the use of the expression `NeumannValue` impose `FiniteElement`, but `Laplacian` not, though historically they appeared at the same time.

Here are some ways to find the answer to this question :

- some error messages may give the information
- after having done `sol=NDSolveValue[...]`, then if `sol["ElementMesh"]` gives a object `ElementMesh[ blabla ]`, `FiniteElement` has been used
- one can do also `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations[...] `` instead of `NDSolve[...]` and examine the resulting object.

Is there something more friendly, above all for beginners who will use preferently the automatic choice ?

Answer (score 13):

**Update:**

There is a new section in the FEM documentation [What Triggers the Use of the Finite Element Method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#1993509248) that has a detailed list of what triggers the usage of the finite element method.

**Previous:**

Ideally, the method you choose does not matter because either finds a solution. However, currently (V12.0) the `TensorProductGrid` (`TPG`) can not deal with arbitrarily shaped regions.

I understand your question that you are looking for a simple rule of thumb. The simplest rules that trigger FEM I can think of are the following:

- If you specify a region (`{x,...} ∈ reg`)
- If you use `DirichletCondition`, `NeumannValue` or `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`
- If the PDE is elliptic and embedding dimension is larger than 1
- If the PDE contains `Inactive` components
- If you write a wave equation but do not specify (enough) initial conditions. The equation will be treated as stationary PDE and solved with the FEM

Specifying `NeumannValue` will lead to FEM since the correspondence to `Derivative` is not one to one (See the section [The Relation between NeumannValue and Boundary Derivatives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html)).

Most reliable is to check if the resulting interpolation function contains an `ElementMesh`.

```
if = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, u[0, y] == 0, 
    u[1, y] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
if["ElementMesh"]

(* NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh[{{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
{NDSolve`FEM`QuadElement["<" 400 ">"]}]*)
```

In case the TPG was used `None` will be returned.

Another hint is that all `FEM` error message tags start with `fem`. So if you see one of those you know `NDSolve` is trying to using `FEM`.

I'll continue to work to make the `FEM` more versatile in future releases.