# Why isn't Derivative equal to NeumannValue?

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

Can someone explain why, if I have

```
u=u[x,t]
```

then

```
Derivative[1,0][u][0,t] == 0
```

doesn't give the same result as

```
NeumannValue[0,x==0]
```

I just want to solve heat/diffusion equation

```
D[u[x,t],t] == D[u[x,t],{x,2}]
```

with 2 bc saying that the derivative with respect to $x$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$ is equal to $0$ (flux=0) and that ic is

```
u[x,0]==Sin[Pi*x]
```

I got it right in *COMSOL* but not in *Mathematica*

Comment: Err... Because the first is a differential equation, and the [second says](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) that _something_ is supposed to be zero at $x=0$? Your question is like asking why `Range[42]` doesn't give the same result as `ListPlot[{1,2}]`.   What is it that you **really** are doing?

Comment: Can you give a complete example?

Comment: I second @Szabolcs: please post the complete _Mathematica_ code you are using. Without it we're not really able to help you.

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140805/5467) user21 writes :"Specifying NeumannValue will lead to FEM since the correspondence to Derivative is not one to one".  I confess that I don't understand the section "The Relation between NeumannValue and Boundary Derivatives" in the linked page.

Comment: In your case zero Neumann value at `x==0` is indeed equivalent to `Derivative[1,0][u][0,t] == 0`, how did you code it? Please add the complete code sample. Also, notice your i.c. is inconsistent with b.c., so you'll face the problem mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871) if you're not using `"FiniteElement"` method for spatial discretization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use DSolve in the normal way.  No need to use NeumannValue in this case.

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]

DSolve[{pde, Derivative[1, 0][u][1, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == Sin[Pi x]}, 
 u[x, t], {x, t}]

(*{{u[x, t] -> 2*Inactive[Sum][((1 + (-1)^K[1])*Cos[Pi*x*K[1]])/
        (E^(Pi^2*t*K[1]^2)*(Pi - Pi*K[1]^2)), {K[1], 1, Infinity}] + 
     2/Pi}}*)
```

Change from `K[1]` to `n` to make simpler and make finite number of terms for plotting

```
u[x_, t_, m_] := 2/Pi + (2/Pi)*Sum[((1 + (-1)^n)*Cos[Pi*x*n])/(E^(Pi^2*t*n^2)*(1 - n^2)), 
     {n, 2, m}]
```

The trick is that the `n = 1` term appears singular to MMA with the denominator and if you take the limit MMA returns a complex result.  Plotting the real portion shows that the `n = 1` term is zero, so we can start the sum at `n = 2`.

```
tp = Table[
   Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t, 200]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {t, 
    0, .2, .005}];
ListAnimate[tp]
```

[image]

Comment: How is a DSolve answer the same as an NDSolve answer?