# NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am facing these error messages,

> NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the
>   derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as
>   differential-algebraic equations.

plus

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

The equation in question is,

```
PDE = D[M[t, x, y], t] == 1/(x^2 + y^2)*D[(x^2 + 1)*D[M[t, x, y], x], x] + 
   1/(x^2 + y^2)*D[(-y^2 + 1)*D[M[t, x, y], y], y]

nv1 = NeumannValue[0, y == 1];
nv2 = NeumannValue[0, y == 0];
nv3 = NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
nv4 = NeumannValue[-Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 + 1)]*Bi*M[t, x, y], x == xf];

Bi = 0.5; xf = 5;

sol = NDSolve[{PDE == nv1 + nv2 + nv3 + nv4, M[0, x, y] == 1}, 
   M, {x, 0, xf}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: what does this pde represent physically? I am asking because having all Neumann BC. and no Dirichlet boundary conditions looks very strange. Most of the time this leads to no unique solution (depending on the physics of the pde)

Comment: @Nasser I took this equation and bcs from here http://dx.doi.org/10.1590/S0104-66322008000100004

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `PDE == nv1 + nv2 + nv3 + nv4` is obviously wrong, because there already exists a `==` in your `PDE`. This is easy to fix of course.

What's confusing is the `Power::infy` warning. I'm not sure why this pops up, maybe `NDSolve` fails to notice `FiniteElement` should be chosen in this case, while [it should be able to](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140805/1871). Anyway, specifying the method explicitly fixes the problem:

```
solution = NDSolve[{Subtract @@ PDE == nv4, M[0, x, y] == 1}, 
   M, {x, 0, xf}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}];

Table[ContourPlot[M[t, x, y] /. solution, {x, 0, xf}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 1, 10, 3}]
```

[image]

`nv1`, `nv2`, `nv3` are omitted because zero Neumann value is the default setting of `FiniteElement`.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a short coming in the detection. Hm, I'll need to dig into the code to see what happens - or better what does not happen in this case...

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is not in the correct form for FEM. Homogeneous Neumann conditions are applied automatically.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Bi = 0.5; xf = 5; reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {xf, 1}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001];
PDE = D[M[t, x, y], t] - 1/(x^2 + y^2)*D[(x^2 + 1)*D[M[t, x, y], x], x] - 
 1/(x^2 + y^2)*D[(-y^2 + 1)*D[M[t, x, y], y], y]

nv4 = NeumannValue[-Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 + 1)]*Bi*M[t, x, y], 
   x == xf];



sol = NDSolve[{PDE == nv4, M[0, x, y] == 1}, 
  M, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, 10}]

Table[ContourPlot[M[t, x, y] /. sol, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 1, 10,
   3}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Consider a solution in a region with a hole (homogeneous Neumann conditions are applied automatically at the edge of the hole)

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Bi = 0.5; xf = 5; reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {xf, 1}]; reg1 = 
 Rectangle[{1, 1/3}, {4, 2/3}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[reg, reg1], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001];
PDE = D[M[t, x, y], t] - 
   1/(x^2 + y^2)*D[(x^2 + 1)*D[M[t, x, y], x], x] - 
   1/(x^2 + y^2)*D[(-y^2 + 1)*D[M[t, x, y], y], y];

nv4 = NeumannValue[-Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 + 1)]*Bi*M[t, x, y], 
   x == xf];

sol = NDSolve[{PDE == nv4, M[0, x, y] == 1}, 
  M, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, 10}]

Table[ContourPlot[M[t, x, y] /. sol, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 1, 10,
   3}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: This PDE isn't equivalent to the original one, you forgot to change the nv4 accordingly.

Comment: @xzczd you're right, corrected, matches your answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev How to construct a prolate or oblate region inside a square and then mesh around it?

Comment: @zhk Are you interested in solving this equation on such a mesh or in general?

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes I want to solve this equation on such a mesh

Comment: @zhk See update to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I saw it. Thx for your efforts. But I want the hole needs to be a prolate not rectangle.

Comment: @zhk OK! Give an accurate description of the region.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I don't know whether you can open this paper or not. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijheatmasstransfer.2019.04.138

Comment: @zhk It will be better if you start a new topic.

Comment: @AlexTrounev How we can use different type of bcs around the hole? Let say I want `M=1` there.

Comment: @zhk Use `bcs = DirichletCondition[M[t, x, y] == 1, 
   x == 1 || x == 4 || y == 1/3 || y == 2/3];
sol = NDSolve[{PDE == nv4, bcs, M[0, x, y] == 1}, 
   M, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, 10}];`