Shallow-water equations on a rotating sphere by using the NDSolve method with a purpose of earthquake-generated tsunami simulation
I'm trying to numerically solve a system of Shallow Water Equations in Wolfram Mathematica 14.0.0 on the rotating sphere by using the NDSolve method with a purpose of earthquake-generated Tsunami simulation. I define necessary physical constants, initial ocean floor profile, initial values of angular speeds and water surface. I also setup time-dependent ocean floor excitation law and atmospheric pressure function.
Shallow Water Gravity Waves Equations are presented below:

Here are my code cuttings:
r0 = 6.4*10^6; (*Earth radius*)
g = 9.81; (*Earth gravitational constant*)
\[Omega]0 = 7.3*10^-5; (*Earth angular speed*)
\[Omega]0 = 0; (*set in order to simplify problem visualization*)
d = 10^4; (*average depth of ocean between surface and floor*)
p0 = 1.013*10^5; (*normal atmospheric pressure*)
\[Rho] = 10^3; (*water normal density*)
\[Nu] = 1.003*10^-6; (*water normal kinematic viscosity*)

\[Theta]min = 0 + \[Pi]/10;
\[Theta]max = \[Pi] - \[Pi]/10;
\[Phi]min = 0;
\[Phi]max = 2 \[Pi];

FloorProfile[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  d/4*Sin[2 \[Theta]]*(1 + 1/2 Sin[\[Phi]]);
Compensator[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  1/(2*g)*(\[Omega]0*r0)^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^2;

\[Theta]exmin = 0.45*\[Pi];
\[Theta]exmax = 0.55*\[Pi];
\[Phi]exmin = 0.95*\[Pi];
\[Phi]exmax = 1.05*\[Pi];
aex = d/100;
tex = 10;

FloorProfileExcitation[t_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  If[t <= 0, 0, If[t >= tex, aex, aex/tex*t]]*
   If[\[Theta]exmin < \[Theta] < \[Theta]exmax, 
    Sin[\[Pi]*((\[Theta] - \[Theta]exmin)/(\[Theta]exmax - \
\[Theta]exmin))]^2, 0]*
   If[\[Phi]exmin < \[Phi] < \[Phi]exmax, 
    Sin[\[Pi]*((\[Phi] - \[Phi]exmin)/(\[Phi]exmax - \
\[Phi]exmin))]^2, 0];

f[t_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  FloorProfile[\[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
   FloorProfileExcitation[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]];
p[t_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := p0;
h0[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := Compensator[\[Theta], \[Phi]];
v0[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 0;
u0[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 0;

tsim = 10^5;

equations = {r0*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\((h[t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]] - 
         f[t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]])\)\) + 
     v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\((h[
          t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]] - f[t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]])\)\) +
      u[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\((h[
          t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]] - f[t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]])\)\)/
      Sin[\[Theta]] + (h[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
        f[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + d)*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\((v[
            t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]])\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(u[
          t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\))/Sin[\[Theta]] == 0, r0*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(v[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(v[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + u[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(v[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]] == 
    u[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*Cos[\[Theta]]/Sin[\[Theta]] + 
     2*\[Omega]0*r0*u[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*
      Cos[\[Theta]] + (\[Omega]0*r0)^2 Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
     g*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(h[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) - 1/\[Rho]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(p[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + \[Nu]/r0*( \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\((Sin[\[Theta]]*\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]v[
             t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]])\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]v[
           t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]]^2), r0*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(u[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + u[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(u[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/
      Sin[\[Theta]] == -v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*u[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*
      Cos[\[Theta]]/Sin[\[Theta]] - 
     2*\[Omega]0*r0*v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*Cos[\[Theta]] - g*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(h[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]] - 1/\[Rho]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(p[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]] + \[Nu]/r0*( \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\((Sin[\[Theta]]*\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]u[
             t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]])\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]u[
           t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]]^2)};


initialconditions1 = {h[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == h0[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   v[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == v0[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   u[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == u0[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
    h[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi] == 2*\[Pi], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, -2*\[Pi]}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
    v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi] == 2*\[Pi], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, -2*\[Pi]}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
    u[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi] == 2*\[Pi], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, -2*\[Pi]}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[h[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi] == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2*\[Pi]}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi] == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2*\[Pi]}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi] == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2*\[Pi]}]]}; 
method1 = 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement"}}}};
region1 = {\[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Element] 
   Rectangle[{\[Theta]min, \[Phi]min}, {\[Theta]max, \[Phi]max}];

initialconditions2 = {h[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == h0[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   v[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == v0[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   u[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == u0[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   h[t, \[Theta], 0] == h[t, \[Theta], 2 \[Pi]], 
   v[t, \[Theta], 0] == v[t, \[Theta], 2 \[Pi]], 
   u[t, \[Theta], 0] == u[t, \[Theta], 2 \[Pi]]};
method2 = 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}};
region2 = 
  Sequence @@ {{\[Theta], \[Theta]min, \[Theta]max}, {\[Phi], \
\[Phi]min, \[Phi]max}};

initialconditions3 = {h[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == h0[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   v[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == v0[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   u[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == u0[\[Theta], \[Phi]]};
method3 = Method -> Automatic;

RunNDSolveValue[opts___] := 
  NDSolveValue[{equations, initialconditions1}, {h, v, u}, {t, 0, 
    tsim}, region1, MaxSteps -> 5000, 
   MaxStepSize -> 50, StartingStepSize -> 1, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, method1, 
   PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, opts];
Module[{time = 
     0}, (Monitor[
      solution = RunNDSolveValue[StepMonitor :> (time = t)], 
      ProgressIndicator[time/tsim]];)]; // AbsoluteTiming

My WM implementation code with plots and some other metadata was uploaded on my Google Drive.
In general, I need to simulate wave propagation on a very specific domain (world-wide ocean landscape) with periodic boundary conditions over latitude.
According to the post, my case could be evaluated only with FiniteElement method (FEM). As it was shown in @SantaP's answer under the post (thanks @xzczd for link), I ought to use PeriodicBoundaryCondition with "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement"} option for FEM in order to obtain stable correct solution.
So, my first toy model is expressed via initialconditions1 & method1 & region1 parameters for RunNDSolveValue function.
However, at some point of simulation I always receive an error "At t == ~18000, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected." When I try to visualize my solution, I also see that it tends to rapidly burst after some iterations. One could see my problem on the animated video below:


Being frustrated about FEM's accuracy by the discussion, I've tried to play with "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"} as it was recommended in the post. This attempt corresponds to initialconditions2 & method2 & region2 parameters for RunNDSolveValue function. Boundary conditions are still periodic here, but further complexification of the spatial domain is unavailable. Unfortunately, this hopeful scheme also crashes with the same error "At t == ~1200, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected." and new warning "An insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable [Theta]. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution."
Moreover, the most trivial default technique initialized with initialconditions3 & method3 & region2 parameters for RunNDSolveValue has the similar behaviour.
Furthermore, I’ve also googled some other different options for NDSolveValue function from here and here, but none of them helped me to stabilize calculation process near the boundary of the simulation region. At the small simulation times I can clearly see my tsunami propagating correctly. In contrast, at the large times numerical interpolation solution explodes with enormous water surface height values without any reason.
So, give me, please, some advice how to deal with such issue. I’m out of ideas ☹

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I've inserted direct formulas of EoM for my problem.

Add a friction.

@yarchik, do you mean kinematic viscosity or viscous drag coefficient?


Please avoid providing code using external links because once the link is down, the post will become useless. Your code isn't that huge, just include it directly in your question. 2. The equation in your code is slightly different from the one in your screenshot, please double check it.



"I received another error “As specified the PDE cannot be discretized using the TensorProductGrid method and will be discretized using the FiniteElement method instead. " It's because you've used PeriodicBoundaryCondition, etc. in your code. (See this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140805/1871) 4. If you insist on FEM for this problem, you need to deal with this issue about PeriodicBoundaryCondition: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220363/1871


@AndreY Your file is about 354Mb. On this forum we can discussed a minimal working example only.


Can you show us the equation system in conservative form?


@AlexTrounev The file is huge because OP has included many outputs in the file. (Unnecessary at all, of course. )

@xzczd Yes, you're right, he included a lot of animation, so the file is very large, and if we remove all this, it will turn out to be very small. ;)

@yarchik, I've improved my EoMs by introducing a kinematic viscosity terms. However, this step didn't stabilizate solution at all for any value of the viscocity coefficient. Actually, such result was expected, because my problems impact only on unexcited boundaries, while friction usually helps to deal with shockwaves.

@xzczd, 1) I'm very sorry for bad presentation of my question! It was my first post on Stack Exchange:) Up-to-date version contains all necessary code. 2) Thanks for checking. Mistake was corrected.

@xzczd, 3) Thanks a lot for your usefull answer! I read these and some other discussions and summed up my new results in ta main part of the question. 4) I've also tried to reformulate my question more accurately in a convinent from.

@alex-trounev, Yes, I'm sorry for too large NB file. Now all essential details are presented here. However, link to my Google Drive still active.

@xzczd, 5) I suppose that it's impossible, because my equations contain a non-potential Coriolis force and friction additions.

@alex-trounev, Last NB version on Google Drive is now free of wasted graphics.

But I suppose the system can be written in a form that's closer to conservative form? (It doesn't need to be a rigorous conservative form. )

@AndreY It looks like you are trying to test the stability of the ocean profile formed by the earth's rotation.

@alex-trounev, Instability on the boundary occurs even for zero angular speed. Or you are speaking about another nuance?

@AndreY I mean the stability of the ocean profile described by OceanProfile :)

There's a $w^2$ term in your picture. Is it a typo?

@xzczd, Yes, It's a mistake:) I've changed a picture. However, this term is responsible for centrifugal force and comes from non-zero Gauss curvature on a sphere: https://perso.math.u-pem.fr/bouchut.francois/publications/nonstandard.pdf

I suggest double checking the equation system. I've tested various methods for handling the singularity at the poles, but the output is always similar: the solution becomes unstable around the pole at about t == 2×10^4 to t == 3×10^4. (Yeah similar to Alex has observed below. ) This seems to suggest that something is wrong with the equation system itself.

We can solve this problem using Method of Lines up to t=0.89 timeSim=89000. But realistic solution we can visualize up to t=30000. Next, we have problems with the wave reaching the gentle shore (North Pole). Note that I have changed the initial and boundary conditions. As a timescale we used timeSim.
 \[CapitalOmega]0 = 0 * 7.3*10^-5;
a0 = 6.4*10^6;
H0 = 10^4;
g = 10;
P0 = 101300;
\[Rho] = 1000;
minTheta = 0;
maxTheta = \[Pi];
minPhi = 0;
maxPhi = 2*\[Pi];
OceanProfile[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  H0/4*Sin[2 \[Theta]]*(1 + 1/2 Sin[\[Phi]]);
Compensator[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  1/(2*g)*(\[CapitalOmega]0*a0)^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^2;
minThetaEx = 0.45*\[Pi];
maxThetaEx = 0.55*\[Pi];
minPhiEx = 0.95*\[Pi];
maxPhiEx = 1.05*\[Pi];
timeSim = 10^5;
amplitudeEx = H0/100;
timeEx = 10/timeSim;
OceanProfileEx = 
  Compile[{{t, _Real}, {\[Theta], _Real}, { \[Phi], _Real}}, 
   Module[{}, 
    If[t >= timeEx, 0, amplitudeEx/timeEx *t]*
     If[minThetaEx < \[Theta] < maxThetaEx, 
      Sin[\[Pi]*((\[Theta] - minThetaEx)/(
         maxThetaEx - minThetaEx))]^2, 0]*
     If[minPhiEx < \[Phi] < maxPhiEx, 
      Sin[\[Pi]*((\[Phi] - minPhiEx)/(maxPhiEx - minPhiEx))]^2, 0]]];
profileFullFunction[t_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  OceanProfile[\[Theta], \[Phi]] + OceanProfileEx[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]];
patmFullFunction[t_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 0;
h0Function[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := Compensator[\[Theta], \[Phi]];
v0Function[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 0;
w0Function[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 0;

Plot[OceanProfileEx[
  t, (maxThetaEx + minThetaEx)/2, (maxPhiEx + minPhiEx)/2], {t, 0, 
  10^-3}]


a = a0/timeSim; equations = {a*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(v[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(v[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + w[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(v[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]] == 
    w[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*Cos[\[Theta]]/Sin[\[Theta]] + 
     2*\[CapitalOmega]0*a0*w[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*
      Cos[\[Theta]] + (\[CapitalOmega]0*
        a0)^2 Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]] - g*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(h[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(patmFullFunction[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)*1/\[Rho], a*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(w[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(w[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + w[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(w[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/
      Sin[\[Theta]] == -w[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*
      Cos[\[Theta]]/Sin[\[Theta]] - 
     2*\[CapitalOmega]0*a0*v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
     g*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(h[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]] - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(patmFullFunction[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]]*1/\[Rho], a*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(h[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(h[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + w[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(h[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/
      Sin[\[Theta]] + (h[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + H0 - 
        profileFullFunction[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]])*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(w[
          t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\((v[
            t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]])\)\))/
      Sin[\[Theta]] - v[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(profileFullFunction[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\) - w[t, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\(profileFullFunction[
        t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)/Sin[\[Theta]] == a*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(profileFullFunction[
       t, \ \[Theta], \ \[Phi]]\)\)} // Quiet;

initialconditions = {v[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == 
    v0Function[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   w[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == w0Function[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   h[0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] == h0Function[\[Theta], \[Phi]]};

eps = 10^-6; bc = {h[t, eps, \[Phi]] == 0, v[t, eps, \[Phi]] == 0, 
  w[t, eps, \[Phi]] == 0, h[t, Pi - eps, \[Phi]] == 0, 
  v[t, Pi - eps, \[Phi]] == 0, w[t, Pi - eps, \[Phi]] == 0, 
  v[t, \[Theta], 0] == v[t, \[Theta], 2 Pi], 
  w[t, \[Theta], 0] == w[t, \[Theta], 2 Pi], 
  h[t, \[Theta], 0] == h[t, \[Theta], 2 Pi]};

mol[n_Integer, o_ : "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

sol = NDSolveValue[{equations, initialconditions, bc}, {v, w, h}, {t, 
    0, 1}, {\[Theta], eps, Pi - eps}, { \[Phi], 0, 2 Pi} , 
   Method -> mol[81, 2]] // AbsoluteTiming

It takes about 2180s on my Silver Pentium. Visualization
framex = 
  Table[Plot[
    sol[[2, 3]][t, x, Pi] - h0Function[x, y], {x, 10^-6, 3.14}, 
    PlotRange -> {-40, 40}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True], {t, 
    0.01, .3, 10^-2}];


framey = 
      Table[Plot[
        sol[[2, 3]][t, Pi/2, y] - h0Function[x, y], {y, 0, 2  Pi}, 
        PlotRange -> {-40, 40}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True], {t, 
        0.01, .3, 10^-2}];


In 2D it looks very funny
frames = 
 Table[DensityPlot[
   sol[[2, 3]][t, x, y] - h0Function[x, y], {y, 0, 2  Pi}, {x, 10^-6, 
    3.14}, PlotRange -> {-40, 40}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
   Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
   PlotPoints -> 20], {t, 0.03, .3, 10^-2}]



I'm afraid the conditions h[t, eps, \[Phi]] == 0, v[t, eps, \[Phi]] == 0,    w[t, eps, \[Phi]] == 0, h[t, Pi - eps, \[Phi]] == 0,    v[t, Pi - eps, \[Phi]] == 0, w[t, Pi - eps, \[Phi]] == 0 are not proper here, because the solution is $\phi$ dependent.

@xzczd In problems involving motion on a sphere, we usually use conditions like these. This is due to the fact that near the poles the physical volume tends to zero.

Its difficult or hopeless to NDSolve waves on a sphere with boundaries because the governing  Laplacian has discrete spectrum. Eigenfunctions of the Laplacian with non-integer eigenvalues belong to parts of the sphere with haed boundaries along some coordinate lines.
The latitude periodic boundary for $\phi$ condition is quite harmless, the equation at poles requires a power factor of $\sin ^m \frac{\theta}{2}$ in order to generate a differentiable smooth function $\sin(m \phi) \ \sin^m\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$.
In a wave equation, any discetization produces errors, that propagate and are tsunamis, too, as you observe in your simulation.
So it's of fundamental importance, to work inside the space of spherical harmonics, representing the discrete solution space in the same way as one uses Fourier methods on a torus: Fourier decompose, time evolute, Fourier compose.

I consciously cut off both polar spherical segments in order to avoid peculiarities in my case. So, my problem doesn't caused by numerical errors from small thetas. Moreover, I observed spontaneous rapid growth on the boundary before my tsunami reached it. So, I guess that problem is hidden in an integration method or in the boundary condition specification. Disproof my statement if it's incorrect, please.

Lets consider s a  bathtub installed on the rotating earth.  Concentrate on the weak solution describing the wave ermerging form a point source,  Mixed boundary conditions are appropriate, damping oscillations of the lowest eigenfrequency modes over some periods, that have no internal friction. From general physical experince I would suspect rotational modes in resonance with earth angular frequency to produce unexpected results. The fact is known from the tides if the rotation frequency conincides with an eigenfrequency of a hydrographic sea basin. The results pile up at the boundary.
