# Losing control over StreamStyle

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

I solved Laplace's equation over a square region. There are Dirichlet BC's (the top wall is fixed at 100, the other walls are fixed at 0).

Plotted result of Laplace's equation is below:

[image: result]

I took the gradient and plotted the result like this:

```
gradientfield = -Grad[sol[x, y], {x, y}];

StreamDensityPlot[gradientfield, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, StreamStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Here `StreamStyle -> Black` gets ignored:

[image: style_broken]

But if I switch `{x, y} \[Element] mesh` to `{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}` then everything is fine:

[image: style_ok]

Does anyone know what makes me lose control over StreamStyle? It is important for me to use `{x, y} \[Element] mesh` because I have several solutions in which there are openings in the middle of a region. Using `{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}` puts streamlines over the empty region. I tested it on Mathematica 10.3.

P.S. I found a way around this. For this I break StreamDensityPlot into StreamPlot (where I use `StreamStyle -> Black`) and DensityPlot. Then I overlap them with `Show[]`. Still, I would want to know what the problem with StreamDensityPlot is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can fixed by just using `Evaluate@gradientfield`.

But the main issue for me is that when, I use `{x, y} ∈ mesh`

```
StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate@gradientfield, {x, y} ∈ mesh, StreamStyle -> Black,
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
```

I get an error,

> StreamDensityPlot::idomdim: {x,y}[Element]mesh does not have a valid
>   dimension as a plotting domain.

But when I do this `{x, y} ∈ square`, everything works fine,

```
StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate@gradientfield, {x, y} ∈ square, 
 StreamStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

This question is linked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144562/neumann-boundary-condition-for-laplace-equation/144571#144571).

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly `Evaluate@gradientfield` changes? I just tried your code and I don't get that error with my Mathematica 10.3. I believe it is because of the bug with mesh that was introduced after the version 10.3.

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov Does `Evaluate@gradientfield` fixed your problem?

Comment: It does solve the problem. Thank you very much! I still don't see what exactly disables StreamStyle in the first place and how `Evaluate@gradientfield` fixes it.

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov you can find the explanation here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8637/all-curves-in-plot-have-the-same-style-cannot-be-fixed-with-evaluate

Comment: You are very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov You are always welcome.

Comment: All done. I think I have somewhere a version of Maple which I might use. Thanks.

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov I dont see u there?

Comment: There I am: https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/171537/viacheslav-plotnikov I received 2 emails and had to do confirmation twice for some reason.

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov Thx

Answer (score 5):

The issue is similar to the classic [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate).

Plotting is one of the more dynamic areas of development in *Mathematica*, so this explanation is based on V11.1.

The initial source of the trouble is that plotting functions such as `StreamDensityPlot` hold their arguments, that is, the expression is what they get and not its value.  In `StreamDensityPlot`, argument is used ***as is*** to determine its type and the subsequent styling of the plot.  It probably should evaluate it at a numerical point in the domain, but that is not how it is currently programmed to behave.  In OP's case, the argument is a symbol and not a vector and `Length[gradient]` is `0`.  This length is passed to a styling function, which thinks, "That's ridiculous, I'm defaulting to the default styling," if I may anthropomorphize.

Here a comparison of using the symbol `gradientfield` as an argument with passing its value with `Evaluate@gradientfield`.

```
Trace[
 StreamDensityPlot[gradientfield, {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
  StreamStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 _Charting`customVectorStyle
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Trace[
 StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate@gradientfield, {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
  StreamStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 _Charting`customVectorStyle
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the OP's case, the styling function evaluates to an empty list, which is then replaced by the default styling of stream lines:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can fix the problem with any method that passes the value of `gradientfield`, such as `Evaluate@gradientfield`.  One can also use `With`:

```
With[{g = gradientfield}, 
 StreamDensityPlot[g, {x, y} ∈ mesh, StreamStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]]
```

However, passing the option `Evaluated -> True` has no effect. The option is not a documented option of `SteamDensityPlot`, but it is present among `Options[StreamDensityPlot]` and generates no errors.

The documentation of [`SteamDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SteamDensityPlot.html) discusses uses of `Evaluate`, but not this specific issue.  From my own point of view as a user, even given the long-standing fame of the question linked at the top of my answer, I consider this an unnecessary constraint on usage (i.e., a bug).

---

*Test Code*

The OP did not supply test code so I made this up:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
gradientfield = {x, y};
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[]];
StreamDensityPlot[gradientfield, {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
 StreamStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Evaluated -> True]
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael E2. That is a very deep explanation. I will make sure to include the code into all of my future questions.