# Mesh does not have a valid dimension as a plotting domain in 11.0

Tags: plotting, mesh, finite-element-method

In Version 11.0, it appears that one cannot plot over a mesh. The following code worked in Version 10.2:

```
$Version
<< NDSolve`FEM`
reg = Rectangle[];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg];
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, Element[{x,y}, mesh]]
```

> 11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)
>
> Plot3D::idomdim: {x,y} ∈ mesh does not have a valid dimension as a plotting domain.

Of course I could have used `Element[{x,y}, reg]` as the plotting domain in this example, but I am working with a complicated mesh built from a BoundaryMesh rather than a region.

Similar behaviour has been observed in [(144610)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144610/losing-control-over-streamstyle/144611#144611) but this was not the question (and it was only an issue for the answerer zhk, who must have been using a different version of Mathematica to the OP).

Comment: It works like a breeze in version 11.3 for macOS, but I recall that version 11.0.1 was quite buggy when it came to `MeshRegion` and `BoundaryMeshRegion`.

Comment: `mesh` is an ``NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh`` a different creature entirely, and wasn't completely supported in viz functions in 11.0. But, it works fine in 11.1. you need to convert to a `MeshRegion` via `MeshRegion@mesh`, but the results are "interesting" in 11.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments above this issue you see was due to a bug in V11.0 Things work fine in Version 11.1 onward. For version 11 you can use something like

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
amesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];
MeshRegion[MeshOrderAlteration[amesh, 1]]
```

To convert a mesh to a first order mesh region.