# Issue in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, symbolic

Why numericall solution is different than symbolic?

```
k = 5;

eq = {D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]*k == D[u[x, t], t], u[0, t] == 0, 
u[1, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == x};

sol = NDSolve[eq, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}];

sol2 = u[x, t] /. First@DSolve[eq, u[x, t], {x, t}];

Plot[{u[x, t] /. sol /. x -> 1/2, 
sol2 /. x -> 1/2 /. {Infinity -> 100} // Activate}, {t, 0, 10}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Numeric", "Symbolic"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871 So an old-fashined way to fix the problem is to set `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}`, but I'm not sure about how to fix it when `"FiniteElement"` is chosen. (I should say the result is somewhat surprising, according to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139233/1871) `"FiniteElement"` seems to be free from this problem. )

Comment: @xzczd.Thanks.`1` for good comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analytical solution is correct. You can correct the numerical solution by fixing your initial conditions. One way is as follows

```
eq = {D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]*k == D[u[x, t], t], u[0, t] == 0, 
   u[1, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == If[x == 1, 0, x]};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]