# boudary condition in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

My question regards the following boundary value problem:

```
NDSolve[
 {
  D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
  u[0, x] == 0, 
  u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0
 }, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}
]
```

The equations describe the temperature `u[t,x]` in a slab or bar.
The problem I encounter is when I try to change the boudary condition `u[t,5]==0` into one which prescribes (thermal) isolation for every instant (t) on the boundary `x=5`. That means the x  derivative on `x=5` is zero  at every instant. How do I define such a boundary condition?

Comment: If you use the finite element method, the problem become very simple. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139233/5467)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 5) == 0
```

or

```
Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 5] == 0
```